# SQL Update master table with new table data hourly based on no match on Composite PK

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008

I have an SSIS task that downloads a CSV file from FTP and renames the file every hour. After that I'm doing a bulk insert of the data into a new table called NEWFTPDATA.

The data in this file is for the current day up to the current hour. The table has a composite primary key consisting of 4 different columns.

The next step I need to complete is, using T-SQL, compare this new table to my existing master archive table and insert any rows that do not already exist based on matching (or rather not-matching on those 4 columns)

Since I'll be downloading this file hourly (for real-time reporting) for each subsequent run there will be duplicate data which I will not want to insert into the master table to avoid duplicating data.

I've found ways to do this based off of the existence of one particular column, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it based off of 4 columns needing to match.

The workflow should be as follows

Update MASTERTABLE from NEWFTPDATA where newftpdata.column1, newftpdata.column2, newftpdata.column3, newftpdata.column4 do not exist in MASTERTABLE

Hopefully I've supplied substantial information for this question. If any further details are required please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **[MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)**

```
MERGE MasterTable as dest
using newftpdata as src
on 
dest.column1 = src.column1
and
dest.column2 = src.column2
and
dest.column3 = src.column3
and
dest.column4 = src.column4
WHEN NOT MATCHED then
   INSERT (column1, column2, ...)
  values ( Src.column1, Src.column2,....)
```

Comment: Thanks Radar. In the interim I've actually stumbled across another way to achieve the same results (I think). Using the following

insert into MasterTable
select * from newftpdata
except
select * from MasterTable

Are there significant benefits to using Merge instead of this process?

Comment: @Herpington_McDerpington, if not exists () insert into is also good , Merge is new construct that will do same but requires less SQL and easy to read.

Comment: I suppose the issue I'd take with MERGE is the necessity to code out all of the columns - there's over 100...which isn't really a big deal since I'd only be doing it once in the stored procedure), but if the other method I'd commented on works as well then I'd prefer to just go with that. Thank you very much for your assistance!

Comment: p1 You could shorten the source part from `using ( select * from newftpdata) as src` to `using newftpdata as src`